# Dynamic underlining of active page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic, underline

Asked a similar question a while ago and tried to build off of my answer but am still having trouble.

I've got a navigation menu that links to different places within the page. I'd like the active pane's link to be underlined. See the jsFiddle for demonstration. The `return false` is a necessary part of the code. I have a javascript function guiding the page to the location instead of jumping to it instantly.

Thank you!

http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/aBuZu/3/

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href="#about" id="nav_about">ABOUT</a><br />
    <a href="#pictures" id="nav_pictures">PICTURES</a><br />
    <a href="#contact" id="nav_contact">CONTACT</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a, a:active, a:visited {
    color:#1d1d1d;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('#nav a').click(function(){
    $('#nav a').css('text-decoration', 'none', function(){
        $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: $(this).css('color', 'underline'); ???
i think you mean
$(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
also, css() accepts either one or two parameters, not three as you wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aBuZu/1/

```
 $('#nav a').click(function(){
    $('#nav a').css("textDecoration", "none"); 
    $(this).css('textDecoration', 'underline');
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: Using border-bottom give you more control to underline too

Answer (score 2):

Easier:

```
$('#nav a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //same as return false
    $('#nav a').removeClass('active');        
    $(this).toggleClass('active');   
});
```

CSS:

```
a {
    color:#1d1d1d;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover, a.active {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).css('color', 'underline');
```

is kinda nonsense. Perhaps color should be text-decoration: [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/aBuZu/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#nav a').click(function(e){
    $('#nav a').css('text-decoration', 'none');
    $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to choose framework jQuery in jsFiddle

Updated JS

```
$('#nav a').click(function(){
    $('#nav a').css('text-decoration', 'none');
    $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    return false;
});
```